# Mongo DB get multiple document collection data in one API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have three MongoDB function for return different collections.

```
    // mongo DB models/user
    module.exports.countUsers = function (callback) {
    User.findOne().where({ 'status': 1}).count(callback);
    }

   // mongo DB models/Cars
    module.exports.countCars = function (callback) {
    Car.findOne().where({ 'status': 1}).count(callback);
    }

   // mongo DB models/orders
    module.exports.countOrders = function (callback) {
    Order.findOne().where({ 'status': 1}).count(callback);
    }
```

Thing is  I  need this all data combine in one GET  API  call.

```js
User = require('./models/user');
Cars = require('./models/cars');
Orders = require('./models/orders');

app.get('/userInfo', function(req, res) {
  let outPut = {}
  //get  data from  mongo db 
  User.countUsers(function(err, count) {
    //A
    console.log(count);
  outPut.coutUsers = count;
  });
  Cars.countCars(function(err, count) {
    //B
    console.log(count);
      outPut.coutCars = count;
  });
  Orders.countOrders(function(err, count) {
    //C
    console.log(count);
      outPut.coutOrders = count;
  });
  

  
  
  
  res.status(200);
  res.json(outPut);
});
```

Above collection, data must assign to blow objects.

```
outPut.coutUsers = '';
outPut.coutCars = '';
outPut.coutOrders = '';
```

I tried a few ways but no luck.

it always  return `{}`, but I need something like    `{coutUsers:10,countCars:10,countOrders :10}`

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the hell (`callback hell`). If you prefer callback style, you can use [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) , it has `parallel` function, the function will help you complete your task.

Or you can convert your function to Promise then you can use them by Promise syntax or `async/await` syntax (recommended).

What is the callback hell?

```
User = require('./models/user');
Cars = require('./models/cars');
Orders = require('./models/orders');

app.get('/userInfo', function (req, res) {
  let outPut = {}
  //get  data from  mongo db 
  User.countUsers(function (err, count) {
    //A
    console.log(count);
    outPut.coutUsers = count;

    Cars.countCars(function (err, count) {
      //B
      console.log(count);
      outPut.coutCars = count;

      Orders.countOrders(function (err, count) {
        //C
        console.log(count);
        outPut.coutOrders = count;

        res.status(200);
        res.json(outPut);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

If you are using node with nodejs verions >= 8.15, you can use `util.promisify` to convert a callback function to a Promise, then you can use them with Promise syntax or `async/await` syntax.

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify;

app.get('/userInfo', async function (req, res) {
  //get  data from  mongo db
  let coutUsersPromise = promisify(User.countUsers)();
  let coutCarsPromise = promisify(Cars.countCars)();
  let countOrdersPromise = promisify(Orders.countOrders)();

  try {
    let [coutUsers, coutCars, countOrders] = [ // Run the tasks collection of functions in parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed.
      await coutUsersPromise,
      await coutCarsPromise,
      await countOrdersPromise,
    ];

    let outPut = {
      coutUsers: coutUsers,
      countCars: coutCars,
      countOrders: countOrders,
    };

    res.status(200);
    res.json(outPut);
  } catch(err) {
    // Error
    res.status(400);
    res.json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Good Sir how I convert this to async/await??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to convert your functions to a Promise base function.

After converting, only thing left is to chain the commands like the following

```
User = require('./models/user');
Cars = require('./models/cars');
Orders = require('./models/orders');

app.get('/userInfo', function(req, res) {
  let outPut = {}

  /*
   * Get data from MongoDB
   */

  // A
  User.countUsers()
    .then(count => {
      outPut.coutUsers = count;

      // B
      return Cars.countCars();
    })
    .then(count => {
      outPut.coutCars = count;

      // C
      return Orders.countOrders();
    })
    .then(count => {
      outPut.coutOrders = count;

      // Finally return a response
      res.status(200);
      res.json(outPut);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Catch errors in between the chains
      // Return server error (Depends on your way)
      res.status(500);
    })
});
```

You can find more information on Promise and how to create a promise based function from
[Mozilla Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and 
[Google Link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)